# Where to get Ubuntu Network Installer

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-installer, installer

I just can't find Ubuntu Network Installer in .msi or .exe format anywhere over the Internet. Where to obtain this Ubuntu Network Installer please? I want to keep my Windows and run Ubuntu alongside.

Comment: The network installer lets you install Ubuntu over the network. Are you sure that is what you need, you write "I want to keep my Windows and run Ubuntu alongside" ? Please take a look at this method to try Ubuntu without install it: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: yes, i dont want to download the whole Ubuntu .iso, i only want the network installer. And the installation option is to run alongside with Windows (im using windows 10)

Comment: it seems UEFI is boring, my windows 10 won't run along-side with Ubuntu, there's no such option when booting Ubuntu from disc to install